# Some download errors in my discrod musicbot

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, bots, youtube-dl

I am making my music bot for discord
but i am having some problem with uploading videos

```
 @client.command()
async def play(ctx, url : str):
    song_there=os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
    try:
        if song_there:
            os.remove("song.mp3")
    except PermissionError:
        await   ctx.send("music is playing right now, use !stop command")
        return
    voiceChannel=discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels,name='General')
    await voiceChannel.connect()
    voice=discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients,guild=ctx.guild)



    ydl_opts={
        'format':'bestaudio/best',
        'postprocessors':[{
                  'key':'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                  'preferredcodec':'mp3',
                  'preferredquality': '192',
              }],
    }
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts)as ydl:
        ydl.download([url])
    for file in os.listdir("./"):
        if file.endswith(".mp3"):
            os.rename(file,"song.mp3")
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
```

in my programm I have more code but it is not that important.
After compile i have this:

```
[youtube] 5RGaoLpBASw: Downloading webpage
[download] Destination: F1 Tokyo Drift-5RGaoLpBASw.m4a
[download] 100% of 1.11MiB in 00:00                  
[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "F1 Tokyo Drift-5RGaoLpBASw.m4a"
    ERROR: 
    Ignoring exception in command play:
```

and this:

```
raise FFmpegPostProcessorError(msg)
youtube_dl.postprocessor.ffmpeg.FFmpegPostProcessorError
```

and this:

```
raise DownloadError(message, exc_info)
youtube_dl.utils.DownloadError: ERROR:
```

and finally this:

```
raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: DownloadError: ERROR:
```

but on my discord server nothing but connecting the bot to the channel happens
however, a file with the .m4a extension appears in the programm directory, which I need to play.

how can i fix these errors?

Comment: It looks like you removed the actual error message from the errors. Can you add them back?